# jQuery datatables plug-in - how to sort select option list

Tags: jquery, datatables

i'm using this plugin https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

and i have a problem with my list of options

http://i61.tinypic.com/f5543t.jpg

now it is 10,12,14,3,4,5,6,7

and i want to have 3,4,5,6,7,10,12,14

it is probably some option to set but i cant find it..

my jQuery code loks like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                var column = api.column( i );
                var select = $('<select><option value="">Wybierz</option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        },
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Wszystko"]],
    } );
} );
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - just remove .sort() in line 20 and it work like a charm :)

Comment: You have mentioned that you need sorted data, removing `sort()` is not a correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of values is sorted as strings not as numbers. Apparently somewhere in that column you have non-numerical data that prevents DataTables from identifying its type.

Please see [column.type](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) documentation for the list of available data types. I believe you need either `num` or `html-num` if you have HTML tags in that column.

Your code needs to be changed so it looks like:

```
 $('#example').DataTable({
     'columnDefs': [{
         // Use your actual column index instead of 0
         'targets': 0,

         // Use 'num' or 'html-num' depending on your column data
         'type': 'html-num' 
      }],

      // Other initialization options
 )};
```

Comment: thanks for your interest, 
I checked your code but and it does not work for me.

Comment: Listed code is an excerpt that will not work by itself. Have you tried changing `targets` from `0` to your actual column index (if it differs from `0`) and adding other initialization options?